# Call External Java Service from Corda Workflow

Tags: corda

Is there any possible way to call an external java service from Corda workflow (acceptor class, more precisely)?

Comment: Can you explain what does that service do?

Answer (score 0):

Corda 4.4 introduces a new flow framework feature (FlowLogic.await API) which allows custom operations to be executed outside the context of the flows. It allows CorDapp developer to suspend a flow when executing custom long-running operations, such as call-outs to external services.

Learn more in the docs: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/api-flows.html#calling-external-systems-inside-of-flows

There is also this video which has a demo of the feature: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDQ4Pdb0RLs